# Regular expressions C# (xxxx-xxxx mask)

Tags: c#, regex

I can not understand how to make regular expression
For example I have mask:
xxxx-xxxx-xxxx where "x" can be a-z or A-Z or 0-9

And have code:

```
            string[] numbers = 
                 {
                     "1a3F-5t5C-FIG0-InFo", 
                     "444-234-2245", 
                     "444.-2344-2245", 
                 };
        string sPattern = "^[a-z0-9A-z]{4}-[a-z0-9A-z]{4}-[a-z0-9A-z]{4}$-[a-z0-9A-z]{4}$";
        var validList = new List<string>();

        foreach (string s in numbers)
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(s, sPattern))
            {
                validList.Add(s);
            }
        }
        Assert.IsTrue(validList.Count==1);
```

But it doesn't work... I have some mistakes in expression. Could you explain why is it wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things spring to mind: "a-z0-9A-z" should be "a-z0-9A-Z" (note the capital Z), and you've got a $ in the middle of the expression which shouldn't be there. It looks like your mask is currently trying to match *four* sets of xxxx rather than three, too.

Try fixing those three things and then update the question if you're still having problems.

Personally I would create an instance of `Regex` for the pattern, btw:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(
    "^[a-z0-9A-Z]{4}-[a-z0-9A-Z]{4}-[a-z0-9A-Z]{4}$");
```

Comment: Does creating an instance give any benefits when you don't need to check multiple strings?

Comment: @Stook: I don't know what the performance implications are either way - but it makes the code *clearer* IMO, and that's likely to be at least as important :)

Comment: Back then I used a small tool (not online anymore) from Brian Delahunty that created precompiled DLLs from regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks! =) I have 4 part of expression not 3=) Instead of [a-z0-9A-Z] I can use something like [\w\d] but it was not interesting=)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using named grouping `(?<name>.*)` which goes great with multiple subsections `((?<str>[^-]+)-?)+`.

Also http://txt2re.com/ may be helpful.

(Note: Not an answer, just some (hopefully) helpfull additional info.)

Comment: This would also mathch "aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-", for example, or am I wrong?